# JQuery validate problem: I have 2 forms on the same page, each one in 2 different tabs but only one the validation is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 forms on the same page but the validation of one of them does not work! and I don't know why..... The following code shows 2 tab panel that contains 1 form each. The second form does not trigger any validation, even a simple check of empty input, but the first one works!!!! Any advice to solve the problem? I read everything about it. It is a legacy code, please help. I don't know more what to do :)

```
    <div class="tab-content">
    
             <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade {% if not page.tab or page.tab == 'searchTab' or page.search_tab == 'variantTab' %}in active{% endif %}" id="searchVariantPane">
                  <div class="row" style="margin: 32px 0 0 0;">
                        <form method="get" action="{% url 'phenodbsearch:search' %}" id="searchForm" name="searchForm" class="form-horizontal">...</form>
                  </div>
             </div>
             <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade {% if not page.tab or page.tab == 'searchTab' or page.search_tab == 'geneTab' %}in {% endif %}" id="searchGenePane">
                  <div class="row" style="margin: 32px 0 0 0;">
                       <form method="get" action="{% url 'phenodbsearch:searchGene' %}" id="searchGeneForm" name="searchGeneForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gene" class="col-md-3 control-label">Gene :</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <input type="search" id="gene" name="gene" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="refgene gene name..." required autofocus />
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
    <fieldset id="varTypeFieldSet" class="text-muted" disabled>
            <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="variantype" class="col-md-3 control-label">Variant Type (required):</label>
                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                         <select id="variantype" name="variantype" class="form-control input-md">
                                                 <option value="0">Select...</option>
                                                 <option value="1">SNV</option>
                                                 <option value="2">Indel</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </fieldset>
    
                                                    <div id="variantTypeIndelFold" class="collapse">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Variant Function (required):</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                    <select id="refgeneGeneLocationIndel" name="refgeneGeneLocationIndel" class="form-control input-md">
                                                                        <option value="0">Select...</option>
                                                                        <option value="1">Frameshift</option>
                                                                        <option value="2">Nonframeshift</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <div id="variantTypeSNVFold" class="collapse">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Variant Function (required):</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                    <select id="refgeneGeneLocationSNV" name="refgeneGeneLocationSNV" class="form-control input-md">
                                                                        <option value="0">Select...</option>
                                                                        <option value="1">Nonsynonymous</option>
                                                                        <option value="2">Exonic;splicing</option>
                                                                        <option value="3">Stopgain</option>
                                                                        <option value="4">Stoploss</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <fieldset id="gZygosityFieldSet" class="text-muted" disabled>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="zygosity" class="col-md-3 control-label">Zygosity (required):</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                    <select id="zygosity" name="zygosity" class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" multiple>
                                                                        <option value="1">Heterozygous</option>
                                                                        <option value="2">Homozygous</option>
                                                                        <option value="3">Compound heterozygous</option>
                                                                        <option value="4">All</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
    
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <p />
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <fieldset id="gFeatureFieldSet" {% if not page.variants and not page.featureIDList %}class="text-muted" disabled{% endif %}>
                                                        {% for letter in 'ABCDEF' %}
                                                            {% with featureName=page.featureIDList|pElementValue:forloop.counter0 %}
                                                                <div id="gFeatureNameFold_{{ letter }}" class="collapse {% if letter in 'ABC' or featureName or page.featureIDList|length == forloop.counter0 %}in{% endif %}">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                                                                <label for="features" class="col-md-3 control-label text-nowrap">Features (required):</label>
                                                                            {% else %}
                                                                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                                                            {% endif %}
                                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                                    <input type="search" id="gFeatureName_{{ letter }}" name="gFeatureName" class="form-control input-sm gFeatureName" value="{% firstof featureName %}" data-target="#gFeatureNameFold_{{ letter|pIncrement }}" />
                                                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" id="gFeatureExclude_{{ letter }}" class="gFeatureExclude" /> Exclude</span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" id="gFeatureID_{{ letter }}" name="gFeatureID" />
                                                                                <div id="gFeatureNameAutocomplete_{{ letter }}" class="autocomplete"></div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                                                        <label>
                                                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="gMatchAllFeatures" name="gMatchAllFeatures" value="true" /> Must match all features
                                                                                        </label>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            {% endif %}
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            {% endwith %}
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </fieldset>
    
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">
                                                                <p>
                                                                    Features entered here will be shared with submitters if there is a match, and submission features be shared with you. There are optional, a least three need to be entered to be shared, up to six can be specified.
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
    
    
                                                  
                                                  
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <br />
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2">
                                                                <button type="submit" id="searchSubmitGene" class="btn btn-default btn-block" disabled>Search</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    
    

 1. First form validation: works well!!!
        
        $('#searchForm').each(function (){
            $(this).validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                invalidHandler: validatorErrorHandlerFunction,
                rules: {
                    variant: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    searchSubmit: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($('#variant').val() === "") {
                                return true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    variant: {
                        required: 'An variant is required to begin a search',
                    },
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-feedback has-warning');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-feedback has-warning');
                    $(element).prev('.glyphicon').remove();
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $(element).before('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>');
                    $(element).after(error);
                }
            });
        });
    
 2. Second form validation => not trigger any validation
  
        $('#searchGeneForm').each(function() {
            $(this).validate({
                onkeyup:    false,
                invalidHandler: validatorErrorHandlerFunction,
                rules: {
                    gene: {
                        required:   true,
                    },
                    searchSubmitGene: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                             if ($('#gene').val() === "") {
                                    return true
                             }
                        }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    gene: {
                        required:   'A gene is required to search',
                    },
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-feedback has-warning');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-feedback has-warning');
                    $(element).prev('.glyphicon').remove();
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).before('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>');
                    $(element).after(error);
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: You dumped way too much irrelevant code into your post. Just the RENDERED markup code for each form is needed in addition to the jQuery.   And the jQuery Validation Engine is not the same plugin. Please don't tag-spam. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchForm').each(function...
```

With that selector, you're trying to grab all forms with `id="searchForm"`.

However...

- you only appear to have **one** form with this ID
- but if you have two forms with the same ID, then you have **invalid HTML**, and one element will be completely ignored.

In any case, you'll need to select something that is common to both.  For example, assign the same class on both forms and use that instead...

```html
<form id="form_1" class="myFormClass">...</form>

<form id="form_2" class="myFormClass">...</form>
```

```js
$('.myFormClass').each(function() {...
```